# How to retrieve XML that contains CDATA, from Database

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, cdata

I need to retrieve XML in the following format

```xml
<mv>
  <v>!CDATA[[some_inner_xml_1]]</v>
  <v>!CDATA[[some_inner_xml_2]]</v>
</mv>
```

I just learned that data in `<v />` will be some other XML. When I thought that data will be an integer, I wrote this and it worked

```sql
select IdentifierText as 'v' from ipmruntime.RecordsToExport where BatchID = 5 for xml path(''), Root('mv')
```

I was trying to use syntax `'v!cdata'` - it doesn't like it. I don't know where to stick `CDATA` in it

I tried another syntax

```sql
SELECT
    1 AS Tag,
    null AS Parent,
    IdentifierText as 'mv!1!v!cdata'
FROM ipmruntime.RecordsToExport
where BatchID = 5
FOR XML EXPLICIT, root('mv')
```

It results in almost what I need

```
<mv><mv><v><![CDATA[47f81be4-b54f-4703-840b-62b306c40842]]></v></mv><mv><v><![CDATA[3ba36a1f-bf75-4ed9-911e-26f10fba5587]]></v></mv></mv>
```

Or, if I use `'v!1'` in the same query, it will give me `<mv><v></v><v></v></mv>` but where than goes CDATA?

But this has each `<v>` wrapped into `<mv>`. Obviously, I am not great with XML/SqlServer combo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way :

```
select 
   1    as Tag,
   null as Parent,
   IdentifierText as [v!1!!CDATA] --[tag name!tag type!tag attribute!other optional setting]
from ipmruntime.RecordsToExport      
where BatchID = 5 
for xml explicit, root('mv')
```

Comment: Thank you. I looked into `!!cdata` syntax. It puts CDATA into `<>` - `<mv><v><![CDATA[5]]></v><v><![CDATA[5]]></v></mv>`. Is this correct?

Comment: I just ran this test - `SELECT
   MultiVal = TypeNode.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
FROM
    @XML.nodes('/mv/v') AS XTbl(TypeNode)` - it seem working with `<>`. Please confirm

Comment: @T.S. the syntax is : ``TAGNAME!TAGID!ATTRIBUTENAME[!..]`` where in this case we don't put any attribute for `<v>` tag, that's why we have `TAGNAME!TAGID![!CDATA]` (square bracket indicates optional attribute, it should be removed in the actual query)